# What does nV/√Hz mean in the context of signal resolution?

Tags: voltage, operational-amplifier, amplifier, noise

From what I have read so far, V/√Hz is an expression for the amount of noise in a bandwidth.

However, I came across a paper where they mention the minimum resolution of a signal required in the design in the units of nV/√Hz:

[image]

I don't understand how this relates to the signal resolution.

Source: Table 3, [Stanslaski S, Herron J, Chouinard T, Bourget D, Isaacson B, Kremen V, Opri E, Drew W, Brinkmann BH, Gunduz A, Adamski T, Worrell GA, Denison T. *A Chronically Implantable Neural Coprocessor for Investigating the Treatment of Neurological Disorders*. IEEE Trans Biomed Circuits Syst. 2018 Dec;12(6):1230-1245. doi: 10.1109/TBCAS.2018.2880148. Epub 2018 Nov 7. PMID: 30418885; PMCID: PMC6415546.](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6415546/)

Comment: Can you quote the relevant parts of that page that you are asking about?

Comment: nV is nanovolts, 1 000 000 000 nV = 1V

Comment: @Matt hi Matt, it's on table 3

Answer (score 1):

In simple terms, the minimum resolution of a signal, as defined in Table 3 of the cited paper, is the minimum level signal that can be detected. It is a function of the system noise level and the signal-to-noise ratio (SNR) required to detect a signal with that background noise. For example, if the system noise level is 50 and the system can detect signals that are twice the noise (an SNR of 2) than the minimum detectable signal (which they call resolution) is 100.Note that there are methods of signal processing that can detect signals below the background noise level (i.e. SNRs of less than 1).

Comment: Thanks for the answer Barry, I understand your point about SNR, but why do you have that sqrt(Hz) in there? in my limited experience, say in ADCs for example, the resolution is how small of a voltage difference can be detected, so say 10 bit ADC with 5V has 5/2^10 resolution, right? how does frequency come in to play here?

Comment: Just to add another point, for instance in Johnson noise (which is just thermally generated noise), the value is expressed in units of V^2/Hz or V/sqrt(Hz), that's what i mean when i say first thing i think about with this is noise rather than resolution

Comment: Noise values in terms of sqrt(Hz) are essentially the density of the noise. To find the actual noise in volts, you need to multiply by the square root of the bandwidth. Since different systems have different bandwidths (even the same system may have multiple bandwidths), it is more convenient to express the noise as this density so that the actual noise can be calculated once the bandwidth is known.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't mean much without analyzing the whole system. At minimum you need to know what the bandwidth of the system is. To convert between nV/√Hz you need to know the Hz. Lets compare a 1 MHz and a 1 GHz system with 10 nV/√Hz of noise and convert it to nV<sub>RMS</sub>.

\$\sqrt{1\ \mathrm{MHz}} = 1000\sqrt{\mathrm{Hz}} \ \mathrm{and}\\ 1000\sqrt{\mathrm{Hz}}\cdot 10\ \mathrm{nV}/\sqrt{\mathrm{Hz}} = \\10000\ \mathrm{nV_{RMS}} = 10\ \mathrm{\mu V_{RMS}}\$

\$\sqrt{1\ \mathrm{GHz}} = 31623\sqrt{\mathrm{Hz}} \ \mathrm{and}\\ 31623\sqrt{\mathrm{Hz}}\cdot 10\ \mathrm{nV}/\sqrt{\mathrm{Hz}} = \\316230\ \mathrm{nV_{RMS}} = 316\ \mathrm{\mu V_{RMS}}\$

If you want to find the resolution, then you need to know the ADC specs, like the voltage range of the ADC and if the signal is being amplified. This requires too much to share in one answer and comprises of a few chapters of information; a good book to read up on how to analyze circuits is [Analog Circuits: World Class Designs](https://books.google.com/books/about/Analog_Circuits.html?id=ppf3dkynmWcC)

For SNR, you'd need to find the amplitude of your signal in RMS and then you could tell what your SNR ratio is.

However, for the example:
A 5 V/2<sup>24</sup> (5 V, 24-bit) ADC would have 0.298 μV of resolution per bit and if comparing the MHz signal above would have 0.298 μV/10 μV of noise and ~33 noisy counts which would be about 5 noisy bits.

Answer (score 0):

Correct, it's not a complete measure of system resolution; it's a bit loose to say that exactly.  They do however suggest a bandwidth in Table 1,

[image]

200nVrms at 150nV/rtHz implies a bandwidth of 1.8Hz, which doesn't seem consistent with the 500Hz center frequency figure, but is within the spectral figure; if they're doing a 256-bin FFT over that bandwidth, the bandwidth per bin would check out; in which case the "bandpower" might be the acquisition bandwidth, and "spectral" the bin size.  This seems plausible enough at a glance, and a reading of the paper, in detail, with this perspective in mind, is likely to explain the meaning behind these figures (I don't really know what "spectral estimate" or "bandpower center" are supposed to mean offhand).